# $(document).on('change', '.phoneCountry', function () { not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In IE 9 `$(document).on('change',` not working for IE9. `.phoneCountry` is the drop down which need some other data when it is selected.

```
$(document).on('change', '.phoneCountry', function () {
    //    event.preventDefault();
        if ('console' in window) console.log("$('.phoneCountry').change");
        if ($(".phoneCountry").val() != "Select") {
            //reset the controls
            $("#phonecountrycode").val('');
}
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: Define "not working". What version of jQuery are you using, and can you post a complete example?

Comment: any number of things ranging from the structure of your dom to invalid html.

Comment: console.log is non existant in IE. try and get rid of that and try again. your if is also a bit strange. It usually something like `if (console & concosle.log)` i think but genrally that only works with webkit based browsers and kills IE

Comment: Re @ppumkin's point: It exists, just only when you have devtools open. The correct check is `if (typeof console !== "undefined') console.log(...);` But what you're doing may also work.

Comment: @ppumkin: No, `if (console...` will throw a `ReferenceError` if `console` isn't defined.

Comment: In IE8? Or IE 11 :) Either way IE is always a pain

Comment: @ppumkin: Both. And 9. And 10. Don't know about Edge.

Comment: Cool.. ill try that next time I am in the mood for torture. James123, what is the error in the dev console? Have you set a breakpoint in there, maybe IE is not even triggering that event.

Comment: Not working means. This method not calling after select of the dropdown list.